# Centos/RHEL 5.5/5.6 supported SCSI adapters

Tags: centos, rhel, hardware-compatibility, scsi

We have a batch of SuperMicro 6014H-82 servers that have Adaptec 2015S SCSI controllers fitted. Unfortunately, according to the bug tracker ([0002087: CentOS installer won't detect harddrives](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=2087)) it looks like in Centos 5.5 and 5.6 support for this is broken in some way. The issue is tagged with "To be fixed in 5.6" but it isn't (we were unable to get Centos 5.5 or 5.6 to install).

There is a workaround described in this bug report involving Centos 5.4  but we tried and failed (with Centos 5.5 and 5.6). Also, even if it did work, I'm not comfortable with this because it is really just a hack.

I happy enough to buy new controllers for these boxes but I'm having a tough time finding out which controllers actually work with Centos 5.5 or 5.6 that have U320 + RAID5 support. I've visited multiple vendor sites but in most cases their supported OS versions are a bit vague.

**Does anyone know of a reliable HCL for Centos 5.5/5.6 or RHEL 5.5/5.6** or can tell me what U320 SCSI controllers with RAID 5 support can be used with Centos/RHEL 5.5/5.6?

I've spent the last two days researching this and come up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging around we found this article:

> [HP XW9300 and Adaptec 2015S Linux Notes](http://www.toolsforteams.com/roller/blog/entry/notes_on_linux_installations)

In summary, all that needed done was to boot into `noprobe` mode:

```
boot: linux noprobe text
```

then specify the driver manually:

```
I2O Block driver (i2o_block)
```

However, after all that time wasted, it was decided that these boxes and SCSI have had their day and are being put out to pasture.